# How to vertical alignment StackPanel in Universal Windows App?

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

How can I align the settings button below to the bottom of the window? `VerticalAlignment="Bottom"` did not make the settings button appear at the bottom of the window. I am using visual studio 2015 Update 2, project template is BlankApp(Universal Windows).

#### My xaml:

```
<SplitView x:Name="MySplitView" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay"  IsPaneOpen="False" 
                        CompactPaneLength="60" OpenPaneLength="250">
<SplitView.Pane>
    <StackPanel BorderBrush="#FF2B2B2B" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush}" RequestedTheme="Dark" BorderThickness="0">
        <Button x:Name="HamburgerButton" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;"
                            Width="60" Height="60" Background="Transparent" Click="HamburgerButton_Click"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="MenuButton1" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE710;"
                            Width="60" Height="60" Background="Transparent" Click="MenuButton1_Click"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Pobierz dane wiosek" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>

        <!-- ... -->

        <!-- here is problem -->
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="MenuButtonSettegins" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE713;"
                                Width="60" Height="60" Background="Transparent" Click="MenuButtonSettegins_Click"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Ustawienia" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
        <!-- here is problem -->
        <Grid Height="100"/>
    </StackPanel>
</SplitView.Pane>
<SplitView.Content>
    <Grid Margin="10,0,-10,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="17*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="19*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <WebView x:Name="browser" Margin="-10,0,10,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" LoadCompleted="browser_LoadCompleted" Loaded="browser_Loading" NavigationStarting="browser_NavigationStarting">
        </WebView>
    </Grid>
</SplitView.Content>
```

#### Actual vs. desired behavior:

[image: Image with the problem]

Answer (score 3):

A `StackPanel` stacks things. I.e. they are necessarily placed one after another, without additional spacing to make further layout arrangements. The `VerticalAlignment` property is ignored in that case.

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly and completely how your XAML is structured, it's impossible to know for sure what the best approach would be. But, there are a couple of strategies that might work for you:

1. Instead of using a `StackPanel` for the pane, use a `Grid`. Add `<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>` for all of the items except the last. For that one, use `<RowDefinition Height="*"/>` so that it will take up the remaining space. Then the `VerticalAlignment="Bottom"` should have the effect you want.
2. Instead of using a `StackPanel` for the pane, use `DockPanel`. Put the last item separately as a child for the `DockPanel`, and set its `DockPanel.Dock` property as `DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"`. Then after that, include a single vertical `StackPanel` into which all the other items are placed; this will default to `Fill` value for the `Dock` property.

WPF has an extensive layout engine, and I'm sure there are other ways to accomplish the layout you intend here, but I think the above two options are among the simplest.

Comment: you can also take help of newly added relative panel. think twice before using stack panel (although this is one of the most used and easy to use container). You will also wonder when scroll will not work inside a stackpanel.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it:

Define 3 `RowDefintions` **assuming** you have one for the `ListBox` or `ListView` which includes the Add and Play item, and one for Settings. To do so, in your `MainPage.xaml` `Grid` **add** 2 `RowDefintions`

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>  <!-- You can adjust the height for this -->
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

After that, make `Grid.Row="0"` in your `SplitView`

Now put the Settings `StackPanel` in a separate `SplitView` (make another 
`SplitView` with same flags, values and everything to have the same style that the first one has) that has `Grid.Row="1"`. This way, you can set it in any position by using `Grid.RowDefintions` (Vertical positioning) and `Grid.ColumDefintions` (Horizontal positioning) method.